# From PHP Webservice not returning encode response correclty

Tags: php, ios, json, xcode, afnetworking

I have written simple PHP code to register user details from my iphone app. and it works fine and return JSON output. i have added that code below

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
include 'connection.php';
$response = array();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

if($username == NULL || $password == NULL || $email == NULL ){

    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Something Empty";

}else{

    $sql = "INSERT INTO User (username, password, email)
VALUES ('".$username."', '".$password."', '".$email."')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Done";

} else {

    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Error";
}
}

echo json_encode($response);
$conn->close();
```

but when i try to check username already exists before adding to the tables. im getting error saying from my  Xcode Log.

`JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.`

```
if($username == NULL || $password == NULL || $email == NULL ){

    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Something Empty";

}else{

   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE username='".$username."'");


    if (mysql_num_rows($query) != 0)
  {
      $response["success"] = 0;
      $response["message"] = "Username Already Exists";

  }else{

      $response["success"] = 1;
      $response["message"] = "That Name Fine";
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is most likely a php error (potentially only a notification or warning depending on your `error_reporting` settings) that is polluting the json output.

You'll need to debug the problem and you may consider the `error_reporting` level for production.

Comment: `$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE username='".$username."'");` will this output something before calling `if (mysql_num_rows($query) != 0)`

Comment: Are you using mysql or mysqli connection?

Comment: Well that's your error then. You've used `mysql_query()`

Comment: Awesome. yes it solved the problem. i changed the code according to mysqli

Comment: is there any advantage or difference between using mysqli or mysql?

Comment: mysql is depreciated so you definitely should use mysqli. mysqli also supports more options and features